# How to make perticular column readonly in excel using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am generating an excel file using apache poi  and i want to make  last two columns read only in that excel file. So i have  tried the locked feature of poi but it is making all cells  readonly , where i want to the last two readonly .Here i am posting what i have done so far

```
   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        sheet.protectSheet("password");
        HSSFRow row = null;

        HSSFCell cell = null;

        /* cell style for locking */
        CellStyle lockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        lockedCellStyle.setLocked(true);
        /* cell style for editable cells */
        CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);


cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                if (null != taskDiaryItem.getDueDate()) {
                    SimpleDateFormat formater = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(InboxItemValue.INBOX_DATE_FORMAT.value());
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(formater.format(taskDiaryItem.getDueDate())));
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                }
                columnNo = columnNo + 1;
                /*** End Change : CR#20 CQ#fklnp00272463 ***/

                cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                if (null != taskDiaryItem.getTaskPriorityDescription()) {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getTaskPriorityDescription()));
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                }
                columnNo = columnNo + 1;

                cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                if (null == taskDiaryItem.getContractNumber() || (taskDiaryItem.getContractNumber().isEmpty())) {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getContractNumber()));
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                }
                columnNo = columnNo + 1;

                cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                if (null != taskDiaryItem.getTaskStatusDescription()) {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getTaskStatusDescription()));
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                }
                columnNo = columnNo + 1;

                if (!fromContext.equals(InboxItemValue.USER_INBOX.value())
                        && !fromContext.equals(InboxItemValue.TEAM_MEMBER.value())) {

                    cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                    if (null != taskDiaryItem.getAssignedToName()) {
                        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getAssignedToName()));
                        cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                    }
                    columnNo = columnNo + 1;
                }

                cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
                if (null != taskDiaryItem.getAssignedBy()) {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getAssignedBy()));
                    cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                }
            } else if(InboxItemValue.PST_INBOX.value().equals(fromContext)) {
                cell = tasksForPSTAndPlacement(taskDiaryItem, cell, row, columnNo, fromContext);
            } else if(InboxItemValue.PLACEMENT_INBOX.value().equals(fromContext)) {
                cell = tasksForPSTAndPlacement(taskDiaryItem, cell, row, columnNo, fromContext);
            }
            j++;
        }
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Inbox.xls");
        response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ServletOutputStream fileOut = response.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to try the opposite to make it working.

Protect the whole sheet and call `setLocked(false)` for the cells which should be editable.

I have tried this sample code here if you run this you will find that cell havinf TEST is editable where as cell having value TEST2 is read only, you can use this  code to build your logic.

```
String file = "C:\\poitest.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

        CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        sheet.protectSheet("password");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("TEST");
        cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);

        Cell cell2 = row.createCell(1);
        cell2.setCellValue("TEST2");


        wb.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: I have alreday tried see my code  if (null != taskDiaryItem.getAssignedToName()) {
                        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(taskDiaryItem.getAssignedToName()));
                        cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
                    }

Comment: can you edit my code i have already tried the solution you r saying  . please

Comment: have you created a protected sheet using Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
sheet.protectSheet("password");